# How to query a row in MYSQL and join results to a row from another table?

Tags: mysql, join

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.userID, buildstatus
FROM meeting a
WHERE buildStatus =  'complete'
INNER JOIN user.contactName ON (a.userID = b.userID)
```

Ok so I'm trying to join these two tables where buildstatus from the meeting table is found to be complete it will then find the user id from the user table and join the contact name to this query.

Unfortunately, whatever I try seems to throw up an error message.

Any ideas how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order of the query clauses have to be correct. switch `join` and `where`

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.userID, a.buildstatus 
FROM meeting a
INNER JOIN `user` b ON a.userID = b.userID
WHERE a.buildStatus = 'complete'
```

Comment: Now it says that user.contactName doesn't exist. It does. I tried this line and now it turns up a syntax error.

SELECT DISTINCT a.userID, buildstatus 
FROM meeting a
INNER JOIN contactName b FROM user ON a.userID = b.userID
WHERE a.buildStatus = 'complete'

Comment: What is your table structure? Is your table called `user`? Try my update please. You should really read up on SQL basics.

Comment: I have a user and a meeting table. Both have a row called userId but that is the only common row.